# Construct the suffix automaton

Tags: code-golf, string

> In computer science, a suffix automaton is the smallest partial deterministic finite automaton that recognizes the set of suffixes of a given string. (Wikipedia)

Given a string \$S\$ consisting of lowercase letters (`a-z`), construct the suffix automaton for it.

A suffix automaton is an array of states, 0-indexed or 1-indexed, depending on your implementation. The **ID** of a states is defined to be its location in the aforementioned array. The **initial state** \$t_0\$ is the state that corresponds to the empty string, and **must be first in the array of states**.

A state is defined as a sequence of 27 integers:

- The first integer is the state's **suffix link**, or the ID of the state that corresponds to the current state's longest suffix that occurs more times than the current state in \$S\$. In the case the this state is \$t_0\$, this value should be equal to a special value that is not a state ID.
- The second to 27th integer corresponds to the state's **transition pointer**, or the state ID that corresponds to this state's string + a letter, for characters `a` through `z` respectively. In the case that such a state does not exist, this value should be equal to a special value that is not a state ID.

For further information on a suffix automaton and how to construct it, see the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_automaton) and the [CP-algorithms page](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-automaton.html).

### Input

The input string will be given in any acceptable format.

### Output

Output the array of states in any acceptable format. Be sure to state the "special values that is not a state ID".

### Example

For the string `abbbcccaabbccabcabc`, the suffix automaton's states should be structured similarly to this (blue edges = transition pointer, green dashed edges = suffix link):

[image: SAM 1]

For the string `ddbadbdbddddbdbcabcdcaccabbbcbcbbadaccabbadcbdadcdcdbacbcadbcddcadcaaaacdbbbcaaadcaddcbaddbbcbbccdbc`:

[image: SAM 2]

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest program (in bytes) wins.

Your code should run reasonably fast (in at most 10 seconds) for a string of length \$10^6\$. (If this requirement is too strict, I will relax the limit.)

Comment: I think the time requirement is too strict. It completely rules out everything except the O(nlogk) algorithm, and in some languages even the O(nlogk) might not run in 2 seconds, rendering some languages completely useless for this challenge. I also think you should set a less ambiguous definition of "your program's return should represent this", because it might lead to conflict regarding what constitutes a representation of a graph and what doesn't.

Comment: @WindmillCookies Concerning time limit: You can construct it in O(n). (My C++ code runs in under 1 second.) Concerning representation: I clearly stated the representation as an array of states. (Ok, I reworded it a bit)

Comment: This is an awesome question.  If only I had time to answer it. There are tags [tag:restricted-time] and [tag:restricted-complexity].  You may want one of those.

Comment: @BaaingCow OK, but still some languages are slow and can't run 10^6 operations in 2 seconds. With that tight of a time limit, everyone will send the port of the same answer and it will not be very interesting.

Comment: @WindmillCookies I am not sure this matters does it? The task is sufficiently complicated that answers are likely to be different in detail even if similar in overall approach.  We have lots of trivial code-golf questions on this site and no one complains that all the answers are implementing the same algorithm.  Also, see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193011/counting-creatures-on-a-hexagonal-tiling . That's a perfectly good challenge despite the existence of very slow languages.

Comment: @WindmillCookies Reasonable, but then can I say "10^6 or the number of array write operations doable in your languages in 0.2 seconds, whichever is less"? Or would it be too complicated?

Comment: @Anush What makes an interesting challenge interesting is the different approaches in the answers. When all answers are the same except the programming language, it won't be very interesting. And yes, I do complain all the answers are implementing the same algorithm in those trivial challenges, just not publicly.

Comment: @BaaingCow I think something around 10 seconds is reasonable for this

Comment: @WindmillCookies Fair, I've changed it to 10 seconds.

Comment: @Anush I'm not sure 10 seconds is strict enough to be called "restricted time"? It's not necessary to stop O(n log ∑) in fast languages and all I want to do is to prevent some blatantly wrong methods (n^2 and above? i guess?) and methods that use builtins to find the suffix array (are there any?) and convert it into a SAM (is that even possible?)

Comment: @BaaingCow I often want to do the same thing. I think any time restriction is "restricted time". For example it is common in code-golf to give answers that you will never be able to run to completion. I won't complain but maybe other people might.

Comment: why not [tag:fastest-code]?

Comment: @ngn There's a linear time algorithm, so this is going to be about micro-optimization (assuming anybody will even bother trying to solve this; suffix automatons are annoying...)

Comment: For what's worth, here is my implementation of suffix automaton. It's late here and I may golf it tomorrow. Use as you wish. https://ideone.com/M5FNM2 (former one has a typo)